# How to compare multiple words separated by comma in an if statement?

Tags: java

I have a variable named title which is having the value "Javascript,XML,XHTML,CSS,Ajax". I need to compare in an if statement if the title equals to the above value some code needs to be run.

I have used

```
if (title == "Javascript,XML,XHTML,CSS,Ajax"){

} else if (title == " ") {

} else {

}
```

When the title is null, the code goes to the second `else` part and gets the correct result. But when the title is equal to Javascript,XML,XHTML,CSS,Ajax the code goes to the last `else` part instead of going to the `if` part.

What mistake have I done here? I have checked the upper lower case and also spelling along with the delimiter comma the string is same just as in the variable title. Then why do I not get the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `==` comparison operator is not correct way to compare string contents. You should instead use the [`.equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
if (title.equals("Javascript,XML,XHTML,CSS,Ajax")) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `==` to compare strings.  You have to use `title.equals("Javascript, ...")` for string comparison; otherwise, you are checking to see if they are in fact the same object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java, you'll need to use `if (title.equalsIgnoreCase("Javascript,XML,XHTML,CSS,Ajax"))`. The equals operator is used to determine if two pointers have the same value (i.e. point to the same object).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(title.equals("Javascript,XML,XHTML,CSS,Ajax")) {
....
}
```

Another advice, you should take a look at some basic Java first!

Answer (score 0):

In Java, strings are objects.  The == operator tells you whether they are the same instance of the same object.  Use the equals(...) method for this instead.